# Pyro4 with callbacks

Tags: python, callback, pyro

I have the following class definition in a py file:

```
class this_obj(object):

    def __init__(self):
         self._apple = 5.0
         self.observ_apple = []

    def setter(self, value):
        if (self._apple != value):
            self._apple = value
            for callback in self.observ_apple:
                callback(self._apple)

    def getter(self):
        return self._apple

    # apply property
    apple = property(getter, setter)

    # binder functions
    def bind_to_apple(self, callback):
        self.observ_apple.append(callback)
```

And I have this main code in another file:

```
import handler_obj

def print_on_change(value):
    print("apple change!!! " + str(value))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = handler_obj.this_obj()
    q.bind_to_apple(print_on_change)
    print(q.getter())
    q.setter(30)
    print(q.getter())
```

If you run this code you can see that it is running. Now I am trying to run the same code with Pyro4. As I was doing this I always run into the following error message:

```
Pyro4.errors.SerializeError: unsupported serialized class: builtins.function
```

for the following line:

```
q.bind_to_apple(print_on_change)
```

My question would be:
Is this even possible with Pyro4 or is this a restriction of the serializer? Can this be solved if I try to use pickle instead of serpent?

If not than is there an alternative to Pyro4 which you can suggest for me for such cases?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found a solution for that. If you change the serializer setting the Pyro4.config.SERIALIZER global variable to "dill", then the function callbacks will be handled too.

Comment: Don't edit the configuration.py file itself, as it is part of the library! Use another way to change the config item (for instance by using the appropriate environment variable)